# How to use python type in List Comprehension

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

How do use the python type in List Comprehension??
Can I?

```
>>> ll
[1, 2, 5, 'foo', 'baz', 'wert']

>>> [x for x in ll ]
[1, 2, 5, 'foo', 'baz', 'wert']

>>> [x for x in ll if type(x) == 'int']
[]

>>> [x*20.0 for x in ll if type(x) == 'int']
[]
>>> type(ll[0])
<type 'int'>
```

Looking for :`[20, 40, 100, 'foo', 'baz', 'wert']`

Comment: `'int'` is just a string. You want `int` (without quotes). `isinstance` is usually more robust than using `type`

Comment: type(1) is a 'type' type ,not 'string' type,  type(type(1))==type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in Python, best practice is to use "Duck Typing".  One way to do that is to use exception handling, which in this case would need a helper function:

```
def safe_multiply(x, y):
    try:
        return x * y
    except TypeError:
        return x

[safe_multiply(x, 20) for x in ll]
```

The alternative duck-typing answer is to see if the object has a method for multiply:

```
[x * 20 if hasattr(x, "__mul__") else x for x in ll]
```

But both of the above have a quirk: in Python it is legal to use `*` with a string, and the result repeats the string:

```
print("foo" * 3)  # prints "foofoofoo"
```

So the best way to go is to use the answer by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.  He didn't actually give you the code, so here it is:

```
[x * 20 if isinstance(x, int) else x for x in ll]
```

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't. Use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead.

Comment: how would use, I was thinking if and else to get the correct output

Comment: Why would you use an `else`? Your original doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
In [6]: [x * 20.0 if type(x) is int else x for x in ll]
Out[6]: [20.0, 40.0, 100.0, 'foo', 'baz', 'wert']
```

Here you're checking type with `type(x) is int`, and if it so - multiply, else you just append x to your resulting list (`else x`), exactly as you wanted to.

Comment: Is it any better now? Sorry, I'm a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "is int" instead of "== 'int'"

[20*x if type(x) is int else x for x in ll]

Comment: aha, I see your purpose now. Modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ll = [1, 2, 5, 'foo', 'baz', 'wert']
>>> [ x*20.0 if isinstance(x, int) else x for x in ll]
[20.0, 40.0, 100.0, 'foo', 'baz', 'wert']
```

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the question, there is an example of the desired output.  The strings should be passed unchanged, not filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use == ,use 'is'
you need to write the code like this:

```
[x for x in ll if type(x) is 'int']
```